# Skim excess power from a resonant circuit without draining it?

Tags: resonance, resonant, self-resonant-frequency

If you have a resonant circuit, oscillating at its self-resonant frequency, how would you extract the excess power without draining it fully? A high Q resonant transformer impedance matched to the circuit perhaps? Is there another way? I actually need DC output so perhaps rectifying before extraction is a good strategy?

Comment: Try things out using a simulator. It's ideal for theoretical experimentation on this type of idea. Been there etc..

Comment: *how would you extract the excess power without draining it fully?* By stopping with power extraction before it is fully drained and/or adding more power into the resonator.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling the power you WANT is greater than you can skim?  The inductor has resistance so it will cause loss and the source has to put power in to deal with that loss.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It must be that smell, that smell of "free energy" ;-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The clue was *excess* with no attributation to where the excess comes from!

Comment: This question is an oxymoron. If you're draining power from it, it's not a high Q resonant circuit any more.

Comment: @Andyaka That sounds like a good idea. What software did you use to simulate?

Comment: Micro-cap 12 is what I use. It's free, its got a full library and it's good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One definition of Q is energy_stored/energy_lost_per_cycle.

Increase the losses, to your pickoff, and you necessarily decrease the Q.

If you have a parallel LC at some point in your oscillator, then a series diode to an output is a good way of getting a DC voltage out, while only loading the circuit at the conduction instants, and leaving it unloaded throughout the rest of the cycle.

For instance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPPwd8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've included the sustaining circuit, as resonant circuits don't just resonate by themselves, especially if you skim off the 'excess power'. I've also included its power supply, just in case anybody is so entranced by the idea of resonance they think they can get free energy out of it.

Comment: Thank you Neil, very helpful!

Comment: Do be aware that diodes have nonzero capacitance.

Comment: @TLW Do feel free to add your own answer, pointing out how the diode's reverse biassed capacitance changes the resonant frequency of the circuit slightly, and why you should care about this effect, compared to the much larger effect that D1 clamping the positive swing to a diode drop above the peak output DC voltage has.

Comment: It's not the frequency change that I was attempting to draw attention to. It's that you're stating "leaving it unloaded throughout the rest of the cycle".

Comment: @TLW Because the diode residual capacitance is not 'loading' it at all, is not abstracting energy, certainly not compared to the massive loading that the diode conducting into the output capacitor effects. In a hand-wavy circuit like this, I think I've been sufficiently detailed. That's the beauty of a forum like this. One person like me comes in with a simple answer. If you think I've been too sparse with detail, you can post your own.

Comment: "the diode residual capacitance is not 'loading' it at all". It absolutely is, assuming that DC output is connected to something with a non-infinite impedance. Capacitive coupling is a thing. This answer is written in a way that makes it sound like this DC output isn't going to affect the circuit at all until you overcome the diode drop and the diode conducts, which is flat-out incorrect. Making another answer to say "no, the other answer is incorrect" is... suboptimal at best.

Comment: This is _especially_ relevant for an otherwise-high-Q resonant circuit.

Comment: @TLW No, you don't make another answer to say a particular answer is incorrect, you make another answer to say 'this is what actually does happen', preferably with numbers for order of magnitude, so that the OP can see whether the distinction that's being made is significant or not for his application.

Comment: @TLW What I mean is make and state assumptions about the OP's operating frequency and oscillator LC ratio, then you can estimate some values for  capacitors C1-C2, and output current and voltage will give you a stab at a reasonable C3. Then see whether the one or two pF of a small signal diode is going to be significant compared to them. What would be interesting is to compare the behaviour of a SPICE simulation with and without D1, maybe increasing its assumed residual C to emphasise any effect, or using a zero capacitance 'ideal' diode. We both might learn something.